# max() doesn't return 10 it returns 1 then 0

Tags: java, split, max

I'm working on a problem where I have to find a separator of the data and also find the highest number from it. I have found the separator, although when I'm trying to complete `findMax` from the data and there is number 33, for example, it doesn't recognize it as 33 but rather it sees it as 3 and 3 separatley.

Could you advise?

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String data = "1;2;33;4;6";
    Operation operation = new Operation();
    operation.findSeperator(data);
    System.out.println(operation);

    System.out.println(operation.maxInt(data));
}

public class Operation {

private SeperatorEnum seperator;
private String data;

public void findSeperator(String data) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d");
    Optional<String> optional = Arrays.stream(data.split(""))
            .filter(e -> !pattern.matcher(e).matches())
            .findFirst();
    this.seperator = Arrays.stream(SeperatorEnum.values())
            .filter(e -> e.getSeperator().equals(optional.orElse(null)))
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow();
}

public OptionalInt maxInt (String data) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d");
    return Arrays.stream(data.split(""))
          .filter(e -> pattern.matcher(e).matches())
            .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
            .max();
}
```

Here is a sample of the data:

```
String data = "1;2;33;4;6";
```

Comment: Shouldn't be '\\d+'?

Comment: As nearly always: your Regex is incorrect. You only match one digit.

Comment: Well, if you want to split by `;` have you considered actually doing `split(";")`? `split("")` will give you an array where every string has a length of 1.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS I have considered splitting by ; although that wouldn't be possible as the splitters in the file are all different. One line is split by " ", second " ; " etc.

Comment: @kofemann Ive tried to use the "\\d+" but it still only shows one digit for some reason

Comment: Was the `\\d+` also included in the maxInt pattern compilation check?

Comment: @Luponius Yes, When I add it to the seperator checker & maxInt it comes back with:

Operation{seperator=SEMICOLON}
OptionalInt[6]

Comment: @wieszak09 Well in that case: You say you already have a method to find the separator, so you should use that found `SeperatorEnum separator` for splitting. Since you didn't include it I don't know how exactly the class `SeperatorEnum` looks like, but maybe something like `data.split(seperator.getSeparatorStringValue())` is possible (Where getSeparatorStringValue would return ";" for the enum SEMICOLON). However you want to accomplish it, in the end you need to split by what is actually separating your numbers and not just do `data.split("")` in your maxInt method as that is simply wrong.

Comment: Thank you @OHGODSPIDERS The above has solved the issue :) many thanks for your input